# error formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message

Tags: wcf

I extracted the content of an existing content in Tridion and I'm trying to save it through tridion core service. I keep getting this error even when the content I'm setting is as simple as this :
component.Content = string.Format("< Content xmlns = \"org.ttg.tpmg.econsult.problemreason\" >");

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013:deltaData. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData. Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 2.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: Please include version of tridion you are using, also what is the type of component object.

Comment: I can see a space between "<" and "C" in "< Content ... "
this might be an issue?

Comment: I think that is exactly the issue; your content is ill-formed XML.